# Resorting Zoomable Treemaps

Tags: d3.js

This question is abstract, but I'm trying to merge two functions of separate treemaps in d3js, and am asking for an appropriate strategy.

In summary, I want to take the resorting ability of this treemap (count,size): 
http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/treemap.html

And apply that to the zooming function of this treemap:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/

The intention is to allow dynamic transitions for resorting, and then click on a cell to zoom into another tier of the data while maintaining the selected sort. If anyone has suggestions, your help would be much appreciated.

In summary, I'm trying to resort the zoomable treemap by replacing the treemap.values data with the accumulate function.  Here's some sample data for a child:

```
{"name": "DataUtil", "value": 3322,"value1": 45,"value2": 87}
```

By clicking a button, the accumulate function needs to re-assign data based on value,value1,value2, etc. to the full hierarchy.  Then, the visualization needs to be updated.

First attempt (not working) can be found on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1ke3feq/):

```
function accumulate(d, boo) {
if (boo == 0) {
    return (d._children = d.children) ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function (p, v) {
        return p + accumulate(v, 0);
    }, 0) : d.value1;
}
if (boo == 1) {
    return (d._children = d.children) ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function (p, v) {
        return 1 + accumulate(v, 1);
    }, 0) : d.value2;
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Merging the functionalities shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Hi Lars, I've added a JSFiddle.  This is resorting the data with an update button.  I'm trying to transition this data, but I'm having trouble with the layered structure of the JSON.  http://jsfiddle.net/cmox0vd6/

Comment: You need to bind the new data to the existing elements, not add new elements -- see the first example you've linked to.

Comment: Right, that's what I need help with :).  I'm trying to understand the accumulator function and then update the display function.  Binding the data in this case seems more involved than updating treemap.values

Comment: Lars, I've added more specific questions in the example above, although I'm still struggling with overwriting the data across all of the hierarchy.

Comment: Well this is what's implemented in the first example you've linked to (lines 24-44). It's basically selecting the existing elements, calling `.data()` again and then setting the styles.

Comment: Lars, thanks for your patience on this, I think this is almost working. I have a new JSFiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/e1ke3feq/1/, this binds new data when the Update button is selected.  This doesn't create a transition, but the data is changed.  One can notice this when click on a zoomable element, and the chart then resorts.  In order to get the transition, I must be missing something with all of the appends going on.  Do you have any suggestions for how to clean up the display function so that I'm not recreating objects but am rather updating them?

Comment: Please have another look at the first example you've linked to. You're calling a function that adds new elements regardless of what elements are there already. **You need to select the existing elements and handle the update selection.**

Comment: Alright, I looked to recall the accumulate function based on button clicks.  Got a little tripped up on appending svg geometry because of all the nested data.  Here's a crude working version: http://jsfiddle.net/aybr33a0/1/